# Babel not running on imports from `node_modules` via Webpack loader

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm having trouble getting Webpack to run `babel` on a file in `node_modules`.  In particular, I'm trying to transform a `.svg` file (from FontAwesome or other `.svg` sources) with a custom webpack loader, then pass that to Babel for a transform to JSX.

Across the many different configurations I've tried, the problem typically exhibits as either:

### 1. `Unexpected token`

> ```
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> <svg ...></svg>
> ```

Which indicates that neither the custom loader nor babel is being applied i.e. the file is simply being passed through without any loader.

### 2. `Syntax Error`

> ```
> SyntaxError: /Users/bmh/Repos/bug-reports/node_modules/icon/ad.svg: 
>   Unexpected token (2:20)
> 1 |
> 2 |     const element = <div>hey</div>;
> ```

Which indicates that the custom loader is working (since for the purpose of the test it's hard-coded to a `<div>hey</div>`), but that the subsequent `babel-loader` isn't being called.

The issue does ***not*** occur when the `.svg` is not in `node_modules`, meaning that both the custom loader and the babel-loader are working as expected.  Either webpack or babel is deciding to not apply babel transforms to files in `node_modules`, and it's not clear how to workaround this problem.

The one suggestion I found that seemed to have weight was to provide `include` and `exclude` arguments to the webpack `module.rules`, but the various permutations I tried didn't seem to work.

#### Reproduce

Repository: https://github.com/brianmhunt/bug-reports/tree/jsx-svg-import

```sh
$ git clone git@github.com:brianmhunt/bug-reports.git`
$ git checkout jsx-svg-import
$ make
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [detailed in bug #736 of babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/736):

> ... convert `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` with same configuration, `babel-loader` [works] as expected.

The explanation was:

> > ... because .babelrc doesn't "leak" across different packages (delimited by package.json)